# Admob returning no ads after requesting correctly

Tags: java, android, xml, admob, ads

I've written the correct code for admob banner ads, but not getting the ads displayed however the ad requests are working but not returning any ads.

Here's the XML code for **`AdView`** in LinearLayout:

```
<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/xxxxxxxxxx">
    </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>
```

Here's the **`MainActivity.java`** code for ads:

```
MobileAds.initialize(this, getString(R.string.original_ad_app_id));
        mAdView = findViewById(R.id.adView);
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
        mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

Here's the string value for **`R.string.original_ad_app_id`**

```
    <string name="original_ad_app_id">ca-app-pub-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx~xxxxxxxxxx</string>
```

Here's the performance on https//apps.admob.com/

[image]

If you know the solution then please let me know.

Comment: try with Test id and check you got the ads ? @Mubashar Hussain

Comment: Are those test ad keys ? If not then always remember to Never post your keys on internet .

Answer (score 2):

*Request* means that your app (or Admob account) tried to get an ad. But this does not mean that it was successful in getting the ad. It may take you a few more days to get and load your first ad. Another reason maybe that your app has too few downloads.

Comment: Another issue is that, it is also not making the new requests since last two days. The day implemented it. It made 16 requests. But after that day it also stopped making requests.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing did u test adding test ads
here is the link
https://developers.google.com/admob/android/test-ads
First test with this
and modify the pub id and try
remember a this
once u update the pub id make sure u only open on ur mobile by building an apk and installing it if u test directly ads will not be shown
this was my previous experience
and is ur app published in play store
if no even that could be an issue why only requests are made
if published ask ur friend to install and check
even I faced this issue but once I published and tested it was resolved
Hopefully, it helps u
Thank you